# Does ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter#quote protect against SQL injection?

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, sql-injection

Does this method protect us against SQL injection?

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rsim/oracle-enhanced/ActiveRecord%2FConnectionAdapters%2FOracleEnhancedAdapter:quote

Comment: Yes it did: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote

Comment: Yes, it's prevent but make sure your query prevent SQL injection as well for reference please check http://gavinmiller.io/2015/fixing-sql-injection-vulnerabilities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it did. We can see the documentation for evidence: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote